# multiple line-heights without extra css class

Tags: css, line, extra

Is there a way to have multiple line heights in an unordered list? See the example below, the normal li's have a line height of 25px, but as soon as the sentence gets too long it will split in the same line height as defined before.

http://i46.tinypic.com/w1pdhi.jpg

I would like to have a line height of 16px once the sentence gets too long, without having to give an extra CSS class to the li.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give the same normal `line-height` to every list-item and apply a `margin-bottom` to them to create room between each other

Jsbin [example](http://jsbin.com/uqejad/1/edit)

Comment: Simple, yet effective. Don't know why I didn't think of this myself! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make the line height depend dynamically on the rendering of a `li` element on one line vs. several lines. You could to mark the multiline `li` elements with a class, but being multiline should normally depend dynamically on the available width, instead of being specified statically.

On the other hand, I think that what you are really looking for is a way of setting the vertical spacing between list items. For this, you would simply set vertical margins or padding on them, using a `line-height` setting that is suitable for the multiline items.